# Windows 10 Computer Not Coming Out of Sleep Mode With Displays Working

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, sleep

I've got a desktop computer with an Nvidia graphics card as listed below. When the computer comes out of sleep, sometimes one monitor does not come up, sometimes multiple (I have three total monitors, two 4K and one 1280x720).  Power cycling the monitors usually brings the computer to all monitors working again.

The password prompt also seems to get in the way. Is there a way to turn password prompting off when the computer comes out of sleep? (The computer is in a secure environment.)

Configuration:

```
Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 10586) (10586.th2_release.160906-1759)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: ASUS
             System Model: All Series
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 04/11/16 15:38:11 Ver: 05.0000B
                Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-5820K CPU @ 3.30GHz (12 CPUs), ~3.3GHz
                   Memory: 65536MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 65446MB RAM
                Page File: 17461MB used, 57712MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\Windows
          DirectX Version: 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
       System DPI Setting: 144 DPI (150 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
                 Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.10586.0000 64bit Unicode

Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 970
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_13C2&SUBSYS_39753842&REV_A1
     Display Memory: 36781 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 4058 MB
      Shared Memory: 32722 MB
       Current Mode: 3840 x 2160 (32 bit) (60Hz)
       Monitor Name: Dell UP3216Q (DP4k60)
      Monitor Model: DELL UP3216Q
         Monitor Id: DEL40C1
        Native Mode: 3840 x 2160(p) (59.997Hz)
        Output Type: Displayport External
```

Comment: Update to Version 1607

Comment: I have a laptop running W10 where after hibernation the display often does not come up. I found that after making it sleep the display always comes back. I configured the lid for sleep/wake, so it's easy to do without needing the keyboard: you can probably configure a short press on the power button to invoke sleep and any key to wake. It's a pain, but I've learned to live with it.

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound I don't think the trigger is the problem. I can 99% of the time cause a change by moving my mouse or k/b and one of the monitors comes back up, just not all of them (and sometimes, none of them but I can see the computer red light getting busy so I know some interrupt has been fired)

Comment: @Ramhound update what to 1607?

Comment: Your out of date installation of a Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound  when I run windows update, it says I'm up to date.  How can I be behind?

Comment: Use the upgrade assistant.  Version 1607 is being rolled out